# rust crate cc is creating unwanted directories

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, rust-cargo

I have a custom `build.rs` file, which is supposed to download a c++ libary from github and build it. My `build.rs` file is seperated into three parts:

1. cloning the github repository
2. compiling all the files using the crate `cc`
3. linking the required libaries

a) If i comment out the second part, the cloning part works just fine and the linking part fails. (just like expected)

b) If i only comment out the cloning part, while already having cloned the repository from "a)" everything works just fine and the application runs.

c) If i delete the `./target` directory and use the whole `./build.rs` file without commenting anything out, the build fails while trying to clone the repository, with the following error: `fatal: destination path '<path to my directory>\target\debug\build\rust_imgui-9999b756f624420c\out/imgui' already exists and is not an empty directory.` Looking at the directory it is complaining about, i can see, that it contains a sub directory "backends". Uncommenting line 8 in `./build.rs` doesn't change anything.

**So the problem is the following:**

Somehow the compiling part of the build script is causing the creation of of the directory `.\target\debug\build\rust_imgui-9999b756f624420c\out/imgui/backends` prior to its execution.

Edit: The creation of the unwanted directory is caused by the lines '''.file()'''.

If you now any way tho disable this behavior or maby a small workaround please leave a comment :)

`./build.rs`

```rust
use std::{process::Command, fs};
use cc;

fn main() {
    let imgui_str = format!("{}{}", std::env::var("OUT_DIR").unwrap(), "/imgui/");
    let imgui_path = imgui_str.as_str();

    // fs::remove_dir_all("target/debug/build/rust_imgui-9999b756f624420c/out/imgui/backends").expect("deleting error");
    
    //clone Dear ImGui 
    Command::new("git").args(["clone", "https://github.com/ocornut/imgui.git", "--branch", "docking", imgui_path]).spawn().expect("cloning failed");
    Command::new("git").args(["-C", imgui_path, "pull",]).spawn().expect("pulling failed");

    //compile Dear ImGui
    cc::Build::new()
        .cpp(true)
        .include(format!("{}{}", imgui_path, ""))
        .include(format!("{}{}", imgui_path, "backends"))
        .include(format!("{}{}", imgui_path, "examples/libs/glfw/include"))
        .file("src/gui/gui_lib.cpp")
        .file(format!("{}{}", imgui_path, "imgui.cpp"))
        .file(format!("{}{}", imgui_path, "imgui_draw.cpp"))
        .file(format!("{}{}", imgui_path, "imgui_tables.cpp"))
        .file(format!("{}{}", imgui_path, "imgui_widgets.cpp"))
        .file(format!("{}{}", imgui_path, "backends/imgui_impl_opengl3.cpp"))
        .file(format!("{}{}", imgui_path, "backends/imgui_impl_glfw.cpp"))
        .file(format!("{}{}", imgui_path, "imgui_demo.cpp"))
        .compile("gui_lib_cc");
    
    //link everything
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=glfw3");
    println!("{}", format!("cargo:rustc-link-search={}examples/libs/glfw/lib-vc2010-64", imgui_path));

    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=gdi32");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=opengl32");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=shell32");
}
```

rust version: 1.59.0

os: Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the commands to clone the repository are started but not waited for to finish. Changing the `.spawn()` to `.status()` changes that.

Applying that change gets rid of the whole issue.